# Test class to run any Organization

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package, metadata-api, salesforce-id

1. I have a class which takes any record id and returns fields name and it's values as well as relationship record's values.
2. Now to write a Test class, i have to create a record.
3. I can try with inserting Account record, but If **Account have mandatory fields other than "Name" in the destination/Installing environment**.Because we don't know what fields are there in every Organization.
4. ***what type of record can i create for this Use case.***

**Any possibility ?**

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could calculate "on the fly" your account fields using `Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();` then you just need to use `isNillable()` method over each field to know if they are required and if true just fill them, then call your test

Comment: Oooh nice.  I hadn't really looked at `isNillable()` before.  What a strange way for Salesforce to communicate a 'required' field.

Answer (score 2):

There is an inherent flaw in simply checking if the field is `nillable`. Sometimes the requirement is more nuanced. Maybe a `Validation Rule` is in place to ensure a specific `Date` field can only be in the future, or makes one of a collection of fields required. There are infinite variations on how `Validation Rules` affect this scenario. You could also have validations applied via `Apex Trigger` in more complex cases.

You also need to think about fields which are *unique*. If you create records in bulk, this consideration is just as important. You may also end up struggling with required Lookup fields, strict picklists, and length constraints.

---

I wrote a tool called `SObjectFactory` and had to work through some of these concerns. You can see it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aalarson/SObjectFactory). My pattern was to implement a `RequiredFieldsCache` and just populate it manually. The basic idea:

```
@IsTest
public class RequiredFieldsCache
{
    public static Map<SObjectField, Object> get(SObjectType sObjectType)
    {
        return cache.containsKey(sObjectType) ?
            cache.get(sObjectType) : new Map<SObjectField, Object>();
    }

    static Map<SObjectType, Map<SObjectField, Object>> cache =
        new Map<SObjectType, Map<SObjectField, Object>>
    {
        Account.sObjectType => Map<SObjectField, Object>
        {
            Account.Name => 'ACME'
        }
    }
}
```

In a `Managed Package`, you're going to have to find a way to make this mechanism configurable, likely via `Custom Metadata Types`. You could build out this cache dynamically using `isNillable()` and `isUnique()`, then fill in the gaps with the metadata object. You may need to build out your `Custom Metadata Type` to enable dynamic provider values in addition to more vanilla schemes.